# With pdfkit, save (write) multiple converted pdfs to separate files in a sequence

Tags: python-2.7, pdfkit

I have multiple htm files in a directory. I used pdfkit to convert to pdf files. Converting works perfectly fine, but I do not know how to write converted pdf's into separate files. Right now, it just overwrites the previous file. Please help. I really appreciated it.

**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'**

I think the best way is to (1) convert to pdf and (2) save the file in a sequence. But I just can't figure out with pdfkit module. Please help. Thank you!

```
import pdfkit
import os
import requests

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\phill\\Desktop\\10k\\HTML')

def htmltopdf(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        pdfkit.from_file(f, '8k.pdf')
        with open('8k.pdf', 'w') as pdf:
            file.write('8k.pdf')

files=os.listdir('C:\\Users\\phill\\Desktop\\10k\\HTML')
for file in files:
    if ".htm" in file:
        htmltopdf(file)
```

Comment: This is because you're always saving the file to `8k.pdf`. Making it use different names each time should save it in different places.